# top vs /proc/pid/stat which is better for cpu% usage calculation

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

Which is the better and more precise in calculating cpu_time consumed by a process?

a) Top
b) cat /proc/pid/stat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of both "top" and "cat /proc/pid/stat" are same at any given point of time.

The difference is the way in which the output are displayed.

For "top" , the output is dynamically displayed on the screen. The output can't be saved to a file, wherein unknown characters are written in the file as it is dynamic. **The output printed on the screen has the status of all the processes.**

For "cat /proc/pid/stat" , the current status of the process is printed on the screen. This is done only once but for "top" until user press **quit** the status is printed on the screen.

 **This command "cat /proc/pid/stat" is more specific to a particular process than printing the status of all the process.**

Answer (score 2):

Top can be used in scripts using the batch mode option. For example, try:
`top -b -n 1` 
But, you will either want to use `-n 2` to get only current info from the second report, or set CPULOOP=1 first and then use `-n 1`.  See: http://linux.die.net/man/1/top for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `top` uses the `/proc` filesystem, so either one is fine, but `top` parses the stat file for you, so I'd use `top`. Note that `top` outputs a dynamic list, so in a script, you should use other means.

Comment: if you call `top -bn1` you can have a static list